# build classpath.properties by building a tree of dependencies of the specified modules using the maven

Tags: java, maven

How can I use the open maven plugins to build a list of classpath to all the dependencies of the specified modules in the project?

for example, I have module-one, module-two, module-three. I want, that in the target of the module-three, I have a file of the form:

```
/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/orm/hibernate-core/6.0.0.Alpha6/hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha6.jar // dependency from module-one
:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar // dependency from module-one
:/Users/user/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar // dependency from module-two
```

sorted in the order I need by modules

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: This is necessary for our system to work. Now this is done by a proprietary plugin for maven. My task is to transfer its work to open source plugins without changing the behavior

Comment: I understand that this is your task. But without explaining the background, the question may not be interesting for a wider audience and it is unlikely that you receive answers.

Answer (score 0):

(It is hard to understand your use case so I'll just answer the question as best as I can understand it without commenting on whether it's a good or wise approach.)

You might be happy with the [`dependency:build-classpath`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) goal:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=/path/to/some/classpath.txt
```